# Giving shadow to segmented control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I would like to know if there is any way through .xib or by code, if shadow can be  provided to the segmented control, if there is then how can it be done..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `UISegmentedControl` to a `UIView` as a subview. And give shadow to the UIView with the help of below code.

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-15, 20);
self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

Don't forget to import QuartzCore Framework.

`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

May be it will help you.

Comment: @uzairdhada Happy coding

Comment: Why can't you do that to `UISegmentedControl` itself instead of a `Superview`?  Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late reply, but this is what worked for me in iOS 9:

```
segmentedControl.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
segmentedControl.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
segmentedControl.layer.shadowOpacity = .85f;
```